# A result about connectedness and closed set.

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Show that if $F$ is a closed and connected subset of a metric space $X$ then for every pair of points $a,b\in F$ and each $r>0$ there are points $z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_n$ in $F$ with $z_0=a$, $z_n=b$ and $d(z_{k-1},z_k)<r$  for $0<k<n+1$. Is the hypothesis that $F$ be closed needed? If $F$ is a set which satisfies this property then $F$ is not necessarily connected, even if $F$ is closed. Give an example to illustrate this.

I really don't understand how I will start. Please someone give me some hints.

Answer (score 2):

**First part:** Consider a point $a\in F$ and $r>0$ and let $A$ be the set of points $b\in F$ for which such a sequence exists. Show that $A$ is non-empty, open, closed (as subset of $F$).

> *To elaborate:* Fix $a\in F$, $r>0$.
>   We define the two (obviously open) sets 
>   $$ U=\bigcup_{x\in A}B(x,\tfrac r2),\qquad V=\bigcup_{y\in F\setminus A}B(y,\tfrac r2).$$
>   Clearly, $F\subseteq U\cup V$.
>   Assume $c\in F\cap U\cap V$. Then there exist $x\in A$ and $y\in F\setminus A$ with $d(x,y)\le d(x,c)+d(y,c)<r$. But from a sequence $z_0=a,z_1,\ldots, z_n=x$ with all steps $<r$, we arrive at the sequence e $z_0=a,z_1,\ldots, z_n, z_{n+1}=y$ with all steps $<r$. This contradicts $y\in F\setminus A$.
>   We conclude that $F\cap U\cap V=\emptyset$.
>   As $F$ is connected, we conclude that one of $F\cap U$, $F\cap V$ is empty. As $F\cap U$ contains $a$, we find that $F\cap V$ and in particular its subset $F\setminus A$ is empty. In other words, $A=F$.

**Second part:** At no point in the above argument did we make use of $F$ being closed. Alternatively: Nothing prevents us from replacing $X$ with $F$, which would automatically make $F$ closed.

**Third part:** Consider $F=X=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ (with induced metric). One can also find a counterexample where $X$ is connected.

> *To eleborate:* Let $X=\Bbb R^2$ (with standard metric) and $$F=\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R\mid xy=0\lor xy=1\,\}.$$
>   Then $F$ is not connected because we can cover it by the disjoint open sets $U=\{\,(x,y)\in X\mid xy<\frac12\,\}$ and  $V=\{\,(x,y)\in X\mid xy>\frac12\,\}$. $F$ is also closed (inverse image of the closed set $\{0,1\}$ under the continuous multiplication map $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$). And finally, $F$ has the property described in the problem statement. In particular, we can "walk" in small steps from any point on the hyperbola to a point far out, then jump to the axis and walk along the axes to the origin, say.

Comment: To show B is open , we have to enter a open ball B(b,t) in B where t<=r and this ball is also in F . If F is open then i can do easily. But here F is closed ,plese tell me how i will do this.

Comment: plese give me the explanation of my above comment.@Hagen Von Eitzen